# How can I change the domain of a URL within a varchar column?

Tags: mysql

I have a database structure where one of my columns (innerLink) has a URL within it.

So that innerLink column will have a URL structured as follows
http://www.123456.com/forums/showthread.php?t=123456

I wanted to change the `http://www.123456.com` to a wholly different URL -->  `http://789.123.com` without affecting the rest of the URL structure (ie. `/forums/showthread.php?t=123456` )

**I need this change to hit every URL in that column that is on the 123456 domain.  I have other URLs such as cnn.com or msnbc.com so I dont want those affected.  The change should only be to make www.123456.com to 789.123.com**

I've never done this type of manipulation with MYSQL before, so was hoping for a bit of guidance before I hose my entire database of about 4000 records :)  I will be doing this through PHPMYADMIN

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) string function

```
UPDATE `table` SET `innerLink` = REPLACE('www.123456.com', '789.123.com');
```